# Adding more input fields on click inside a bootstrap input-append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

im using twitter bootstrap.I need a 
1.select-box + input field with autocomplete.
2.Add row button which adds an input field
3.remove row button
4.save button which submits all the values selected.

```
<div class="well-large">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button></br>
        <div class="input-append btn-group">
            <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text">
            <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach($cars as $ar){?>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i><?php echo $ar;?></a></li>
                <?php }?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var cars = <?php echo json_encode($cars) ?>;
    $("#appendedInputButton").autocomplete({
        source: cars,
        fillin:true
    });
```

I had tried many ways but either one of these is not working.Can someone suggest me a way to solve this .Mainly on add row .

Comment: please show attempts made. Also provide raw html, not server code. Nothing shown indicates and sort of `"Add"` button. A demo in jsfiddle.net is always helpful

Comment: Here is the demo in jsfiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/7gWt3/

Comment: can't place php code in a live demo. Use browser source html. I was going to help but not going to create the sample data needed or refactor php to html. If you add new autocomplete elements, have to initialize plugin for the new one after you add it

Answer (score -1):

For One >> Does the autocomplete need to pull data dynamically, like typing into google URI bar auto searches google, or just isolate fields based on typed criteria.  i.e. you type "a" and it displays only annie, annabelle, amy, then you type "n" making your field "an" and no longer displaying amy

For Two  >>  check these jquery methods [http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/] and pick the one that best suits you.  The bind it to a button and have the jqueryStuff() function add the DOM stuff you want

```
<button onClick="jqueryStuff()">Add Row</button>
```

For Three >> Use the same thing as 2 but from [http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/].  Do you want to have check boxes then remove, or the easier way and just remove the last on the list.

```
<button onClick="jqueryStuff()">Remove Row</button>
```

Comment: Here is the demo in jsfiddle . jsfiddle.net/7gWt3